# Should a Float or Int be used in this RNG?

Tags: random, multiplication

I am using a simple [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to generate random numbers. The problem is, the result is behaving inconsistently depending on if I use `Floats` (known as `Numbers` in some languages) or `Ints`

```
// Variable definitions
var _seed:int = 1;
const MULTIPLIER:int = 48271;
const MODULUS:int = 2147483647; // 0x7FFFFFFF (31 bit integer)

// Inside the function
return _seed = ((_seed * MULTIPLIER) % MODULUS) & MODULUS;
```

The part I'm having difficulties with is the `(_seed * MULTIPLIER)` part. If `_seed` and `MULTIPLIER` are Ints, the `int*int` multiplication ensues, and most languages give an `int` as a result. The problem is, if that `int` is too large, the resulting value is truncated down.

Is this integer overflow behavior "supposed to be done" in RNGs, or should I cast `_seed` and `MULTIPLIER` to Floats before the multiplication in order to allow for larger variables?

Answer (score 1):

LCG's are implemented with integer arithmetic because floating point arithmetic is only approximate - a floating point implementation will diverge from the integer implementation and won't yield full cycle for the generator.  Even a double only has 52 mantissa bits, which is fewer than required to store the product of two 32 bit ints with guaranteed precision.  With modulo arithmetic it's the low bits that are significant, and they're the ones at risk of getting lopped off.

Solutions:

1. You should be doing the intermediate arithmetic using 64 bit integers, then
   cast/convert the result back to 32 bit ints after the modulo operation.
2. Explicitly break up the multiplication into low bits/high bits
   components, and then recombine them after the modulo operation. 
   This is what Schrage did to achieve [this portable FORTRAN
   implementation](http://epub.wu.ac.at/1288/1/document.pdf) of a relatively popular (at the time) LCG.

Comment: _"Even a double only has 52 bits"_ < However, you are only multiplying a 31 bit integer with `48271`. Would that be enough to fit inside a 52 bit Double/Number without losing accuracy?

Comment: For this particular LCG, yes, but if you're willing to go to a double why not use a long?

Comment: Alas, neither AS3 nor Haxe (the languages I am targeting) support that data-type. They are limited to 32 bit and 31 bit integers respectively, as well as a floating point data type with 52 bits of accuracy. JavaScript only seems to support the latter.

Comment: If you check out the paper by Schrage, it illustrates how to break up the multiplication so no intermediate results exceed 31 bits.  It's in FORTRAN, so it would need translation to AS3/Haxe, but it's pretty straightforward.  I had no problem migrating it to C 30 years ago.